# PHP getting blank pages after submit a form + signal Segmentation fault (11)

Tags: php, mysql, osx-snow-leopard

I few days ago I update my macbook pro to snow leopard, and since then some php files are not showing.

This is what happens:

I created a php form, when going to 'http://localhost/webform.php' I can see the form just fine. Then, once I submit the form, I just get a blank page.

I enable error and warnings reporting under php.ini to make sure I'm not missing something, but still I'm not getting anything, just the blank page.

Then I checked under apache log files, and what I notice is that every time I submit the form I see the following line coming up under the apache logs:

> [Wed Apr 07 21:40:28 2010] [notice]
>   child pid 70223 exit signal
>   Segmentation fault (11)

Comment: Can you post the code that is entered after submit?

Comment: Do other forms exhibit the same behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you tagged this question with <kbd>mysql</kbd>, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you've run into [this issue](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2141886&tstart=0).

I'd suggest commenting out your call to `mysql_close()` and/or `mysql_connect()` and verify that it is indeed one of those lines that is producing the segfault.  The suggested work-around is to always pass the optional database handle to those calls.  However, there are other workaround suggested in that link, so I would try to narrow the problem down and see if any of the suggestions there fix it.

Comment: Yes, before I posted here, I read the link you sent. Thanks to this article, I found that the problem relies with mysql, and this is why I tagged this post with mysql. However, you gave me the solution. I commented out mysql_close() and it worked! After days! Of course I was missing the argument, the database-handle inisde mysql_close(). So, by doing mysql_close($handle), fixed the problem.
One point for you. Thank you very much.